# LocationManager's requestLocationUpdates() creates a notification

Tags: android, kotlin, locationmanager

I am tracking the user's location from a foreground service using the Location Manager. I create my own notification to display the foreground service but when I start tracking the location of the user, Android creates its own notification. This notification isn't created in the Android emulator but is created on my own device which is a Xiaomi Redmi 7 running Android 9.

In the picture below you can see my custom notification which I created in the foreground service as well as another notification which claims to be using the Fused Location Provider service which I believe I am not using.

Is it possible to remove this notification or at least customize the style of it? Thanks!

```
private fun startLocationTracking() {
    locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    val criteria = Criteria();
    criteria.accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE;
    criteria.powerRequirement = Criteria.POWER_HIGH;
    criteria.isAltitudeRequired = true;
    criteria.isSpeedRequired = false;
    criteria.isCostAllowed = true;
    criteria.isBearingRequired = false

    criteria.horizontalAccuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH
    criteria.verticalAccuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        throw RuntimeException("Location tracking started but permissions have not been granted");
    } else {
        locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(updateIntervalInMilliseconds, updateDistanceInMeters, criteria, locationListener, null)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After altering the line of code that requestsLocationUpdates, the extra notification is styled appropriately.

```
locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager!!.getBestProvider(criteria, true), updateIntervalInMilliseconds, updateDistanceInMeters, locationListener, null)
```